# For each loop using Java Iterator

Tags: java, foreach, iterator

So I've been looking over some java code that i understand is used for a foreach loop but it seems like it is overly complicated.

I have a Control.java file that contains properties.

I have a Controls.java file that uses Iterator and takes Control as the data type.

```
public class Controls implements Iterable<Control>{
    protected ArrayList<Control> controls;

    public Controls()
    {
        controls = new ArrayList<Control>();
    }
    public Controls(ArrayList<Control> controls)
    {
        this.controls = controls;
    }

    public ArrayList<Control> value()
    {
        return controls;
    }

    public void add(Control ctrl)
    {
        this.controls.add(ctrl);
    }

    public void add(Controls ctrls)
    {
        for(Control ctrl : ctrls)
        {
            this.controls.add(ctrl);
        }
    }

    public void remove(Control ctrl)
    {
        if(this.controls.contains(ctrl))
        {
            this.controls.remove(ctrl); 
        } else
        {
            for (Control c: this.controls)
            {
                if(c instanceof ContainerControl)
                {
                    ((ContainerControl)c).controls.remove(ctrl);
                }
            }
        }

    }


    public Control get(String name)
    {
        //stuff here
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Control> iterator() {
        return controls.iterator();
    }
}
```

Other files use it as such:

```
public void dumpInstantiation(StringBuffer buf)
{
    for(Control control : controls)
    {
        control.dumpInstantiation(buf);
    }
}
```

To my understanding this is just a foreach loop with the added benefit of adding or removing (or calling any other method) as each control is iterated. As a java newbie a couple questions come to mind though:

1. Is there an easier way to implement this? Is this how it is usually done?
2. Is there any other benefits of doing it this way?
3. Is there a way to do this without ArrayList and Iterator?

Comment: I'm not sure what you think is "overly complicated".  `ArrayList`s have iterators, so that you can say `for (SomeType x : list)` on them.  This `Controls` class just implements `iterator()` by passing through the `ArrayList` iterator, so that `for (Control control : controls)` is equivalent to going through its private `ArrayList` field.  That part isn't complicated at all.  The `add` and `remove` methods have nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there an easier way to implement this? Is this how it is usually done?

In order to use the Java `foreach` construct, your class needs to implement the `Iterable` interface, and provide enough functionality within the required methods to "iterate" over the list and return each item. Usually this means you need to know when there are items remaining and a way to return each one in step. The interface API will tell you if a method is "required" (ie: the method must be declared, but it can provide no implementation) or not. An easier method would be to leverage an already existing collection type, so you don't have to make your own.

> Is there any other benefits of doing it this way?

It's a good way to provide a nice method to allow users to iterate over your list, and it makes the class compatible with other interfaces that operate on `Iterable`

> Is there a way to do this without ArrayList and Iterator?

You could wrap your class in an existing collection that already implements iterator, but this will be up to you.

Comment: Thanks! I understand it a bit more now

Answer (score 2):

So, a for-each loop has two 'arguments'.
 1. the variable to which is assigned the value of each item of an array one by one.
 2. the array or ArrayList etc.

An example:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] numbers = new int[] {3,8,5,2};

        for (int i : numbers)
            System.out.println(i);

    }
}
```

Prints:

```
3
8
5
2
```

You see, it's not that difficult!

And, instead of a normal array, you could use the ArrayList class to dynamically add/remove items:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        numbers.add(3);
        numbers.add(8);
        numbers.add(5);
        numbers.add(2);
        for (int i : numbers)
            System.out.println(i);

    }
}
```

Prints the same.

Did this answer your question?

Comment: For the first example would i need to use List<String> numbers= new ArrayList<int>(); instead of int[] numbers = new int[] {3,8,5,2}; because im under the impression that you CANT do foreach loops with normal arrays.

Comment: int[] numbers **is** actually a normal array, so you can.
But note you can't use primitive data types (such as int, byte, etc) with an ArrayList. You have to use eg 'ArrayList<Integer> = new ArrayList<Integer>();' instead.
Oh, and a String means text, not a number.

Comment: Thanks, i thought you couldn't (which made me super confused) and i didn't know about the primitive data types which makes sense because my example used its own. I also meant to write it all as String but changed my mind midway when i reread your example.

Comment: Also take a look at [this](http://chortle.ccsu.edu/Java5/Notes/chap09C/ch09C_2.html).
So: primitive types also start with a **lower case** character, but an Object should always start with a **upper case** character (eg String, Integer, etc).
By the way, with the <> you describe what type of data is in the ArrayList. You can also use <Object> if you want to put different types in it, but if you want to for example calculate something with a number, you have to use '(Integer)someList.get(_aNumber_)'. (casting the value to Integer)